# A finite axiomatization of the join of the commutative and associative properties

Tags: universal-algebra

Consider the lattice of equational theories of a single binary operation $*$. The meet of the theory axiomatized by commutativity and the theory axiomatized by associativity is simply the theory axiomatized by both of them. What about the join? Is there a finite axiomatization of the join? I conjecture that it is axiomatized by the equation, $(x*y)*x=x*(y*x)$. Is this true? If not, is there some other finite axiomatization, and if so, can someone exhibit such a finite axiom set.

Comment: In less lattice-theoretic language, you're just asking about equational axiomatizations of the set of equational consequences of the sentence $$[\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)]\vee[\forall x,y,z(x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z)],$$ right?

Comment: Algebras satisfying your proposed equation are called [flexible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_algebra). Flexible algebras include algebras which are neither commutative nor associative such as the octonions.

Comment: The join may be not finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: Basically, we want to finitely axiomatize $\mathrm{HSP}(A\cup C)$ where $A$ is the class of associative magmas (semigroups) and $C$ is the class of commutative magmas.

Comment: @Berci: it's clearly finitely axiomatisable by the axiom Noah gave. The question is whether it is axiomatisable by equations (which it isn't, see my answer).

Comment: What is clearly finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: I would suggest posting this question to MO.

Comment: What would an infinite axiomatization look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial answer: I don't know about a finite equational basis, but the "flexible law"
$$(x*y)*x=x*(y*x)\tag1$$
is insufficient: the identity
$$((x*y)*z)*(x*(y*z))=(x*(y*z))*((x*y)*z)\tag2$$
follows from the associative law, and it follows from the commutative law, but it does not follow from $(1)$.

Let $\mathbb F$ be any field not of characteristic $2$ or $3$. If we define
$$x*y=\frac23x+\frac13y$$
then the magma $(\mathbb F,*)$ satisfies $(1)$ for all $x$ and $y$, but does not satisfy $(2)$ if $z\ne x$.

Note that
$$x*y=y*x\iff x=y.$$
Now
$$(x*y)*z=\frac23\left(\frac23x+\frac13y\right)+\frac13z=\frac49x+\frac29y+\frac39z$$
and
$$x*(y*z)=\frac23x+\frac13\left(\frac23y+\frac13z\right)=\frac69x+\frac29y+\frac19z,$$
so
$$(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)\iff z=x,$$
so
$$(x*y)*x=x*(y*x),$$
that is, $(1)$ holds. Also
$$((x*y)*z)*(x*(y*z))=(x*(y*z))*((x*y)*z)$$$$\iff(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)\iff z=x,$$
so $(2)$ does not hold unless $z=x$.